# Result of the APEX method is empty outside experience builder

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, query, knowledge, wire

I'm using the following method to query articles from the Knowledge__kav object. It returns the values properly inside the community Experience builder. However when it comes to the normal page it returns an empty array.
I'm confused because it seems like the code is working properly but there is still (maybe a permission?) issue when I want to use the page outside of the Experience Builder

```
  @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
   public static String getRenewalsArticles() {
       List<Knowledge__kav> articles = [SELECT ArticleNumber FROM Knowledge__kav WITH 
       SECURITY_ENFORCED LIMIT 20];
           
       return JSON.serialize(articles);
   }
```

This is the LWC part:

```
    articles
    @wire(getRenewalsArticles)
    wiredArticles(result) {
        if (result.data) {
            console.log('getRenewalsArticles');
            console.log(JSON.parse(result.data));

        }
        if (result.error) {
            console.error('getRenewalsArticles error: ', result.error);
        }
    }
```